# Application Did Open from background iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiapplication

How can I determine when myApp is opened even when it is already opened in the background?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`- (void) applicationWillEnterForeground` seems to be the method that you're looking for.

Comment: I believe the class in which the method is called has to be the `UIApplicationDelegate`, so you have to declare that first in your @interface.

Comment: I'm new to objective-c and not sure exactly how to do that. @rien333

Comment: In your header file, change the interface declaration to this:

`@interface YourClassName: NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>`